# Automapper doesn't work as it should

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-4

I am using `AutoMapper 4.2.1.0` and I have defined my maps as follow.

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Order_Detail, Order_DetailDTO>();
        });
MapperConfig = config;
```

Then I use `MapperConfig` in my code to do this :

```
var builder = MapperConfig.ExpressionBuilder;
return ((IQueryable<TEntity>) property.GetValue(_db, null)).ProjectTo<TDto>(builder);
```

but when `TEntity` is `Order` and `TDto` is `OrderDto` i am getting an exception that says :

> Missing map from Order to OrderDTO. Create using
>   Mapper.CreateMap

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I have got it:
Instead of :

```
return ((IQueryable<TEntity>) property.GetValue(_db, null)).ProjectTo<TDto>(builder);
```

I should write :

```
return ((IQueryable<TEntity>) property.GetValue(_db, null)).ProjectTo<TDto>(MapperConfig);
```

Passing the config object itself into ProjectTo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a mapper using the MapperConfiguration object.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Order_Detail, Order_DetailDTO>();
});

// Make sure mappings are properly configured (you can try-catch this).
config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

// Create a mapper to use for auto mapping.
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var orderObject = new Order { /* stuff */ };
var orderDto = mapper.Map<OrderDTO>(orderObject);
```

Comment: I want to use `ProjectTo` so I have to use ExpressionBuilder like it is mentioned in this article : https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/